# In facebook marketing api leadgen_context_cards edge is not accepting cover_photo

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am following https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/create/v2.8 to create context card for lead ad. document says it will accept cover_photo field. 
But if we try to create context from Graph API Explorer with following params

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/xxxxxx?method=POST&path=<PAGE_ID>%2Fleadgen_context_cards&version=v2.8&title=sample-title-1&style=PARAGRAPH_STYLE&content=[%22sample%20content%201%22]&button_text=Get%20Started&cover_photo=http://xxxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/sample/sampleimage.png
```

its showing following

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 1,
    "fbtrace_id": "xxxxxx"
  }
}
```

And if we click on fgtrace_id it showing following

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: xxxxx",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 803,
    "fbtrace_id": "yyyyyy"
  }
}
```

If we remove `cover_photo` param we are able to create context cards.

Thanks.

## Update 1

I have tried to upload the actual image file. Still facing same issue. Following is code and response.

```
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(GRAPH_FACEBOOK_LEADGEN_CONTEXT_CARDS);

        File file = new File(IMAGE_PATH);
        ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, ContentType.create(MimeTypeUtils.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE));

        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        builder.addTextBody("access_token", ACCESS_TOKEN);
        builder.addTextBody("title", "sample-title-1");
        builder.addTextBody("style", "PARAGRAPH_STYLE");
        builder.addTextBody("content", "['sample-title-1']");
        builder.addTextBody("button_text", "Get Started");
    // builder.addPart("cover_photo", cbFile);
    // builder.addBinaryBody("cover_photo", file);
    // builder.addBinaryBody("cover_photo", file, ContentType.create(MimeTypeUtils.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE),IMAGE_PATH);
    // builder.addBinaryBody("cover_photo", new FileInputStream(file));

    httppost.setEntity(builder.build());
    System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
    if (resEntity != null) {
        System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
    }
```

Response:

```
executing request POST https://graph.facebook.com/167067040143315/leadgen_context_cards HTTP/1.1
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
{"error":{"message":"An unknown error has occurred.","type":"OAuthException","code":1,"fbtrace_id":"CHG1SYDq9zn"}}
```

## Update 2

With following code I am able to create context card. but cover photo is missing.

```
URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(
                GRAPH_FACEBOOK_LEADGEN_CONTEXT_CARDS);
        uriBuilder.setParameter("access_token", ACCESS_TOKEN);
        uriBuilder.setParameter("title", "sample-title-1");
        uriBuilder.setParameter("style", "PARAGRAPH_STYLE");
        uriBuilder.setParameter("content", "['sample-title-1']");
        uriBuilder.setParameter("button_text", "Get Started");
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uriBuilder.build());

        File file = new File(IMAGE_PATH);
        ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file,
                ContentType.create(MimeTypeUtils.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE));
        byte[] bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);

        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
         builder.addPart("cover_photo", cbFile);
        // builder.addBinaryBody("cover_photo", file);
        // builder.addBinaryBody("cover_photo", file,
        // ContentType.create(MimeTypeUtils.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE),IMAGE_PATH);
        // builder.addBinaryBody("cover_photo", new FileInputStream(file));
        // builder.addBinaryBody("cover_photo", bytes,
        // ContentType.create(MimeTypeUtils.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE),IMAGE_PATH);

        httppost.setEntity(builder.build());
        httppost.addHeader(new BasicHeader("Content-Type",
                ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA.getMimeType()));
        System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
        if (resEntity != null) {
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
        }
```

Comment: All the cURL examples on that page use the syntax `-F 'cover_photo=@image1.jpg'` - which means, it is an actual file upload. Unless it is explicitly documented anywhere that you can just pass an image URL instead, you can assume that that’s not possible for this endpoint.

Comment: did not get it "it is an actual file upload" mean its only possible through focebook provided UI and its not possible through apis. I tried by uploading a image to page then passing image Id there, that is also not working.

Comment: No, it means you have to perform a file upload via API, instead of passing a URL. That means, you must send your data in basically the same way, as an HTML form with an input type=file would.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. I have tried to upload actual image with simple java client. still same issue. See my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my observation in https://business.facebook.com's UI. Its first uploading image and passing id in `cover_photo_id`.

Uploaded unpublished photo to `page/photos` and passed generated Id in `context_card`'s `cover_photo_id`. and its worked.